# Regex to match an IP range?

Tags: java, regex

Can someone help me with a regular expression to match a range of IPs. It should match something like this:

```
"203.0.113.0-203.0.113.255"
```

I tried the following but that only matches for a single IP:

```
((?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})(?:/((?:(?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})|\\d{1,2}))?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have regex that will match single IP then just add `-` and repeat your regex

```
String singleIPRegex = "yourRegex";
String rangeRegex = singleIPRegex + "-" + singleIPRegex;

if (someString.matches(rangeRegex)){
    //do your stuff
}
```

Also as singleIPRegex you can use

```
(([01]?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])
```

part

```
([01]?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])
```

will accept:

- `[01]?\\d{1,2}` -> range 0-199 including numbers started with 0 or 00 like 01, 001
- `2[0-4]\\d` -> range 200-249
- `25[0-5]` -> range 250-255

Answer (score 2):

You can split the String in 2 components

```
String[] splitResult = ipRange.split("-");
```

and then use this pattern for each substring

```
string pattern = @"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
```

Your pattern will actually not work, due to the fact that each IP section only goes up to 255

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(?:/((?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})|\d{1,2})){2}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
String data = "This http://example.com is a sentence 203.0.113.0-203.0.113.255 https://secure.whatever.org that contains 2 URLs.";


    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s((\\d{1,4}\\.?){4}-(\\d{1,4}\\.?){4})\\s");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a regex for an IP Range in this page https://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/ipregex/

For your case,the generated regex is `^203\.0\.113\.([1-9]?\d|[12]\d\d)$` for IP Addresses within the range `203.0.113.0 to 203.0.113.255`