# Python regex to match IP range

Tags: python, regex, ip

I want to match IP range using a Python regex.

For Ex. the google bot IP range as follow

66.249.64.0 - 66.249.95.255

```
re.compile(r"66.249.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")
```

I can not figure out how to do this? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525974/regex-to-match-an-ip-range) one done using Java.

Comment: Are you trying to locate an ip address within a larger text, or do you have a string which only contains the ip address?

Comment: @Joel Cornett : I have a text file with ip addresses, I want to filter some ip addresses from it

Comment: Side note: if you're doing a lot of work with network addresses, you may want to check into the [netaddr package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
re.compile(r"66\.249\.(?:6[4-9]|[78]\d|9[0-5])\.\d{1,3}$")
```

if you are motivated you can replace `\d{1,3}` by :

```
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

Explanation:

A regex engine doesn't know what a numeric range is. The only way to describe a range is to write all the possibilities with alternations:

```
6[4-9]  |  [78][0-9]  |  9[0-5] 

6          can be followed by    4 to 9   --> 64 to 69
7 or 8     can be followed by    0 to 9   --> 70 to 89
9          can be followed by    0 to 5   --> 90 to 95
```

Comment: Excellant..:) Worked Well, Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more thing, Could you please explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `socket.inet_aton`:

```
import socket
ip_min, ip_max = socket.inet_aton('66.249.64.0'), socket.inet_aton('66.249.95.255')

if ip_min <= socket.inet_aton('66.249.63.0') <= ip_max:
    #do stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

The last digit is:

```
[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]
```

The 3rd digit is:

```
6[4-9])|[78]\d|9[0-5]
```