# How can I find an IP address in a long string with REGEX?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to find out how can I extract only the **correct** IP address from a very long string.
The problem is that my code extract the IP address even if a part of it has more than 3 digits (which is incorrect).

I tried to learn more about Python REGEX, but I don't know exactly how to stop it at maximum 3 consecutive digits after a dot.
What I mean is that if an IP is `1.2.3.4` it finds it correctly, which is indeed correct, but if an IP is `1.2.3.4567` it also finds it correctly, which is not correct. I don't know how to say to it that if a group has more than 3 digits, than that's not an IP address.

```
import re

secv = "akmfiawnmgisa gisamgisamgsagr[sao l321r1m r2p4 2342po4k2m4 22.33.4.aer 1.2.3.5344 99.99.99.100 asoifinagf sadgsangidsng sg"

b = re.findall(r"[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", secv)

print(b)
```

It prints `1.2.3.5344` and also `99.99.99.100`, but `1.2.3.5344` is not an IP address because it has more than 3 consecutive digits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex to match IP range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672155/python-regex-to-match-ip-range)

Comment: you just need some boundary, like $ or \s, \b to wrap the valid IP : `\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b`

Comment: It does *not* print 1.2.3.5344. It does however print 1.2.3.534, which is a valid expression for your regex (but not a valid IP address, as it is above 255). The issue is that it is followed by another digit. You could use a look-ahead and require next character to *not* be a digit, to avoid finding 1.2.3.534 if that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, IWHKYB! It worked. But JohanL, how can I check if the next character is a digit or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

secv = "90.123.1.100 akmfiawnmgisa gisamgisamgsagr[sao l321r1m r2p4 2342po4k2m4 22.33.4.aer 1.2.3.5344 99.99.99.100 asoifinagf sadgsangidsng sg 13.18.19.100 1.2.3.4"

b = re.findall(r"(?:\s|\A)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?=\s|\Z)",secv)

b = list(filter(lambda x: all([int(y) <= 255 for y in x.split('.')]), b))


print(b)
```

To make it more interesting I added IP addresses at the beginning and end of your string. I am assuming that the ip address needs to be separated by white space on both sides if not at the beginning or end of the string. So I added to the REGEX at the beginning a non-capturing group **(?:\s|\A)** that will match either a white space character *or* the beginning of the string. I have also added to the end of the REGEX a *lookahead assertion* (?=\s|\Z) that will match a single white space character or the end of the line *without consuming any characters*. The above prints out:

```
['90.123.1.100', '99.99.99.100', '13.18.19.100', '1.2.3.4']
```

Comment: This is not valid regex for a IP address. E.g. it will match `999.999.999.999`...

Comment: @R2RT That is very true. If you look at the REGEX for a  *completely* valid IP, it is rather lengthy. The point of this question was primarily to ensure you weren't getting inadvertently a 4-digit last component. So the thrust of my offering was the testing of the context that the desired string being sought was in. Another way to handle the more thorough test would be after running the above REGEX to then filter the results by splitting each result on the '.' character and ensuring each component was 255 or less (or whatever the rule is).

Comment: @R2RT I have gone back and added such a filter.

Comment: The point of the question was "extract only the correct IP address from a very long string". SO is supposed to be repository of good answers on good questions, not just solutions to current OPs problems. Even though you have helped OP and he may be satisfied, further readers may be not. I'd upvote if you take it into account.

Comment: @R2RT I believe the solution now does that. It doesn't have to ALL be done exclusively by the REGEX -- that was not the requirement. The C++ language is context sensitive yet is parsed with context-free grammars relying on semantic processing (e.g. the use of symbol tables) to determine whether the inputted program is valid.

Comment: Even though I would not use `C++ compiler does that, so this simple function should also do it` reasoning, you are right, it does its job. I wouldn't be surprised if there is some class of problems where it is faster than complex proper IP regex. +1'd, as said.

Answer (score 0):

Just search for the pattern `[1-2]?[0-9]{1,2}` occurring 4 times separated by a dot. Optionally anchor your regex pattern with a word boundary at the beginning and end

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b(?:[1-2]?[0-9]{1,2}\.){3}[1-2]?[0-9]{1,2}\b', secv)
['99.99.99.100']
```

Comment: It worked but it also consider an IP address a sequence like */12.12.12.12 with those chars before 12. So what I did, I put ' +' at the beginning at at the end of the seq to check if the ip address is surrounded by whitespaces.